# IIS appcmd.exe doesn't exist in system32\inetsrv on EC2 Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, windows-server

When I try to enable wfastcgi:

```
IIS configuration tool appcmd.exe was not found at [C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe]
```

It's an EC2 instance on AWS. Windows Server 2019. I looked, and it's indeed not there. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to open the "Turn Windows features on and off", and then select "IIS Management Scripts and Tools" under "Internet Information Services"->"Web Management Tools".

[image]